# In grid trading, is a fixed price level grid equivalent to a dynamic grid?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, high-frequency

I am trying a grid trading bot that shifts the grid around the current market price within a minimum and maximum price.

I lack context on how such strategy compares with a fixed grid centered around a set price.

What would be the pros and cons of such approaches?

For a long strategy, would such dynamic grid be the equivalent to a fixed grid for which the center price is the maximum price of the dynamic grid?

Is there such thing as a standardized terminology in grid trading?